# Alterar o resultado de um valor TD para uma imagem em tabela dinâmica

Tags: javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma mapa de disponibilidade visual, e criei uma tabela dinâmica, até ai tudo certo. Preciso pegar o resultado das `<td>` e transformar em imagens.

Exemplo: minha `<td>` retorna `900`, preciso alterar esse valor para uma imagem X; minha `<td>` retorna `100`, alterar esse valor para imagem Y. entenderam?

Segue abaixo meu JavaScript.

```
var div = document.getElementById("situacao1");

            //var dataset = DatasetFactory.getDataset("colleague", null, null, null);
            //var dataset = DatasetFactory.getDataset("dsEmpreendimentos", null, constraints, null);
            try {
            var dataset = DatasetFactory.getDataset("dsUnidadeVenda", null, constraints, null);
            div.innerHTML = showDataset(dataset);
            } catch(erro) {
                div.innerHTML = erro;
            }
        }

function showDataset(dataset) {
    var tabela = "<table id=minhaTabela>";

    //Monta o cabeçalho
    tabela += "<tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.columns.length; i++) {
        tabela += "<th>" + dataset.columns[i] + "</th>";
    }
    tabela += "</tr>";

    //Monta os registros   
    for (var x = 0; x < dataset.values.length; x++) {
        tabela += "<tr>";
        var row = dataset.values[x];
        for (var y = 0; y < dataset.columns.length; y++) {
            tabela += "<td id=td_sit>" + row[dataset.columns[y]] + "</td>";
        }
        tabela += "</tr>";
    }

    tabela += "</table>";
    return tabela;
}
```

O retorno do JavaScript no HTML é esse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só tem uma coluna de resultado.

Segue abaixo o retorno do Resultado, da pergunta.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bruno, você deseja alterar o conteúdo da `<td>` de **caractere 900**, para uma **imagem**?

Comment: Sem saber a estrutura da tabela fica difícil, porque não se sabe que coluna vc quer pegar os valores... ou seria de todas as colunas?

Comment: só tem u ma coluna que retorna os codigos.

Comment: Mas qual é a coluna? a primeira, a segunda, a terceira....

Comment: Editei minha pergunta e coloquei uma imagem do retorno do JS no HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma (veja comentários no código):

```js
// seleciona as TDs
var cols = document.querySelectorAll("#minhaTabela td");

// percorre as TDs
for(var x = 0; x < cols.length; x++){

   // pega o número da TD
   switch(Number(cols[x].textContent)){
      
      // insere a imagem de acordo com o número dentro da TD
      
      case 100:
      cols[x].innerHTML = '<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">';
      break;
      
      case 900:
      cols[x].innerHTML = '<img src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg">';
      break;

   }
   
}
```

```css
img{
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id=minhaTabela border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>
         col
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         100
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         900
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         100
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

No seu caso, coloque o código dentro do `try` após o `div.innerHTML`:

```
try {

   var dataset = DatasetFactory.getDataset("dsUnidadeVenda", null, constraints, null);
   div.innerHTML = showDataset(dataset);


   // seleciona as TDs
   var cols = document.querySelectorAll("#minhaTabela td");

   // percorre as TDs
   for(var x = 0; x < cols.length; x++){

      // pega o número da TD
      switch(Number(cols[x].textContent)){

         // insere a imagem de acordo com o número dentro da TD

         case 100:
         cols[x].innerHTML = '<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">';
         break;

         case 900:
         cols[x].innerHTML = '<img src="https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg">';
         break;

      }

   }

} catch(erro) {
   div.innerHTML = erro;
}
```

### Usando um objeto

Você também pode criar um objeto e ir guardando o caminho das imagens de acordo com o número. Acho que fica mais fácil de organizar e enxuga mais o código:

```js
var imgs_ = {
   "100": "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg",
   "900": "https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg"
}

// seleciona as TDs
var cols = document.querySelectorAll("#minhaTabela td");

// percorre as TDs
for(var x = 0; x < cols.length; x++){

   // insere a imagem de acordo com o número
   cols[x].innerHTML = '<img src="'+imgs_[Number(cols[x].textContent)]+'">';

}
```

```css
img{
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id=minhaTabela border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>
         col
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         100
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         900
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         100
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sam, obrigado pelas respostas, mas não entendi uma coisa, devo montar a tebela no HTML?
Porque eu monto o meu java script assim.

                            <div name="situacao1" id="situacao1">

Comment: Não. A tabela que coloquei acima foi só exemplo. Peraí que vou atualizar a resposta pra ficar melhor

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Deve funcionar, aí vc só altera os `src` das imagens que vc quer colocar

Comment: Cara deu certíssimo, obrigado mesmo, era isso que eu precisava.

Comment: vou adicionar na resposta uma forma ainda mais simples.. só um instante

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu, não deixe de marcar ✔... té mais!

Comment: esse outro mais enxuto eu substitui no lugar do anterior e não funcionou

Comment: Coloquei o código pra funcionar na resposta. Se vc executar veja que funciona tb :)

Comment: achei o erro tinha deixado o catch dentro do var img=, agora eu certo obrigado....

Comment: Sam, desculpe incomodar novamente, mas voce estava certo eu precise adicionar mais duas colunas, como faço com este código que me passou, como faço para selecionar a terceira coluna, onde vai ficar o código.

Comment: É só trocar isso: `var cols = document.querySelectorAll("#minhaTabela td:nth-child(3)");`

Comment: Só me tira uma dúvida isso é jquery? essa funçao td:nth-child(3)?

Comment: Não tem jQuery aí não. O :nth-child(3) é um selector CSS, que seleciona o 3º elemento especificado.

Comment: cara ficou top vou postar, o print. valeu mesmo....

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, amigo.
Não sei se entendi bem a sua dúvida. Tem como dar mais detalhes?
Se sua dúvida for sobre como alterar o atributo "src" da tag `<img>` você pode fazer isso usando jquery mesmo.
Atribua um id para a tag `<img>` e depois faça o seguinte:

```
$("#id_tag_imagem").attr("src", "caminho_arquivo_imagem.jpg");
```

Se isso não te ajudar, comenta aqui nos dando mais detalhes sobre a sua dúvida pra que fique mais fácil te auxiliar.

Abraços.